# Convert json list to string

Tags: python, arrays, json

I've a json like this taken from vgg image annotator.

```
"5213c8b86f225.image.jpg40172": {
"filename": "5213c8b86f225.image.jpg",
"regions": [{(...)},
            {(...)}]
}
```

I want to convert this json into a format that mask rcnn reads like this:

```
"5213c8b86f225.image.jpg40172":{
  "filename":"24631331976_defa3bb61f_k.jpg",
  "regions":{
     "0":{(...)},
     "1":{(...)},
      (...)}
  }
```

I tried the following code:

```
with open(val_json, 'r+') as f:
  vgg_json = json.load(f)
  mask_json =vgg_json

  for key in vgg_json:
    i=0
    for shape_attr in vgg_json[key]['regions']:
      mask_json[key]['regions'][str(i)]=shape_attr
      i+=1
  f.seek(0)       
  json.dump(mask_json, f, indent=4)
  f.truncate()
```

It won't work and give me the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The entire json file is here: 
    https://github.com/fabioaraujopt/maskrcnn_custom/blob/master/via_region_data.json

Sorry 'hey' was just my test din't realize!! 
The true value is now changed!

Comment: What's the `hey`?

Comment: `mask_json` and `vgg_json` reference the same dictionary.

Comment: sorry, 'hey' was just to check if error was the same, the code was not fixed, is str(i), giving same error anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think what's going on is that when you try to assign a value with a string key to the list (`mask_json[key]['regions']['hey']=shape_attr`). As Python has helpfully pointed out, you can't do that. Here's your code, modified with a few lines to do what I think you want to do:

```
with open(val_json, 'r+') as f:
  vgg_json = json.load(f)
  mask_json = vgg_json

  for key in vgg_json:
    copy = {}  # make a dict to hold the values you want
    i=0
    for shape_attr in vgg_json[key]['regions']:
      copy[f'{i}']=shape_attr  # note that I'm using i here, rather than 'hey'
      i+=1
    mask_json[key]['regions'] = copy  # Replace what was in regions with the new dict we created
  f.seek(0)       
  json.dump(mask_json, f, indent=4)
  f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy each sub-dictionary and but replace `regions` with a dictionary

```
with open(val_json) as f:
    vgg_json = json.load(f)

mask_json = {
    k: dict(v, regions=dict(enumerate(v['regions']))
    for k, v in vgg_json.items()
}

with open(val_json, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(mask_json, f, indent=4)
```